# Translation of the classic Floquet theory paper

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, translation-request, mathematical-french

It [1] is a highly cited seminal paper for the Floquet theory, so I guess this paper has already been translated into English. Could anyone please give me a link for it? Thanks in advance.

[1] Floquet, Gaston. "Sur les équations différentielles linéaires à coefficients périodiques." In Annales scientifiques de l'École normale supérieure, vol. 12, pp. 47-88. 1883.

Comment: I very much doubt there is a translation. French and German math papers are very rarely translated into English because most mathematicians can make out the gist from equations and shared words.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I am not majored in math. Could you please tell me some standard textbooks or novice-oriented articles about Floquet theory?

Comment: It's a graduate level topic, see e.g. [Basic Floquet Theory](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~ward/teaching/m605/every2_floquet1.pdf) and [Hsu, Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications, Ch. 3](https://www.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Applications-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00GNTCKJ6)